# how to get nearby devices available with gps using the same app

Tags: android, gps, location, maps, google-nearby

I am working on a app which shows nearby blood donors. How can I get the users using my app near my location with a specific blood group and show them as marker on google map ??
Any help appreciated.

Comment: The question is too vast. Try to optimize.

Comment: I want to get current lat longs of users using my app nearby me....

Comment: Save donor's data on your server and use rest API's tp fetch results,just pass your current lat lng with blood group and get desire results.(use google direction API to calculate distance at your back end or any other approach of your choice.)

Comment: check this blog post to get current location--https://gagandroid.blogspot.in/2016/03/get-current-location-in-activity-in.html

Comment: Your app involves collection of data (which can be lat,long,blood group, phone no., name,etc) which needs to be send to a server. While searching for required blood group donors you have to send lat, long and blood group. And the result is displayed in the map with multiple markers. First you try adding markers in google maps. Then you have to create server side api for posting and quering data. The app involves network request and google maps. So first setup google maps from [link] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start and proceed further

Comment: I'm curious what the point of this is.  Do you expect me to find someone nearby for a quick refill?  What possible use would this be?

Comment: @GabeSechan I am using it to find nearby blood donors.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server to save all your clients position (longitude / lattitude). Then, each app can ask the server where are the other users, and then you can locally compute what you need.